# What is the search engine address for Google?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, search

I want the address to use when adding a search engine into another browser's search bar, Pale Moon to be exact. So not `https://www.google.com`.
Is there an easy way to find these addresses for websites? like for example, Yahoo, Wikipedia, etc?

If I look at the settings in Chrome, all I can find is this:

```
{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}
```

I've been searching for this on Google, but Google's search algorithms have been falling in quality as of late; most of my advanced searches (ie word + word + "phrase") fail to get me much in the way of relevant results.

Answer (score 5):

You actually have the answer right there:

`google.com/search?q=%s`

`%s` is substituted for your search query. Test it by visiting `google.com/search?q=Superuser`. You'll find it returns search results for 'Superuser'.

Answer (score 4):

```
https://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}
```

for further tips, google this keyword `google search parameters url`

alternatively, install [Add to Search Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar). To use, right click on any search text field and select "add to search bar". now, if you really want to extract the search url, open `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{profile folder}\searchplugins\{search engine}.xml`.

you would get something like:

```
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://www.google.com/search">
  <Param name="ie" value="utf-8"/>
  <Param name="oe" value="utf-8"/>
  <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
</Url>
```

you can then construct the url from {template} and {param}. in this case the full url is

```
https://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&q={searchTerms}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will make good use of this!